# How to use robotframework SAP Gui Library keyword to iterate through a grid made using GuiLabel Objects

Tags: robotframework, sap-gui

I am trying to write robot-framework script to automate SAP transactions with the help of SAP GUI library.

I have a window which has got table like view created using `GuiLabel` objects:

[image: SAP GUILabel Form Format Attached.]

I would like to find those elements by text instead of hardcoding element IDs. Is there any way possible for the same?

Comment: What have you tried already, can you share the Robot Framework code and the relevant HTML code.

Comment: Hi Sandra, SAP logon is a desktop application and hence couldn't figure out how html code could be produced. Requesting  to  please let know if any details should be provided by me.